# How to remove FXAA in threejs outline example?

Tags: three.js, post-processing, fxaa

threejs outline example: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_postprocessing_outline

I tried not to use FXAA in the example, for FXAA leads to poor resolution. But nothing was rendered after I'd removed FXAA codes, and no console information appeared.

Is FXAA a must when using outlinepass? How can I remove FXAA?

Answer (score 2):

Just setting `outlinePass.renderToScreen = true` does not work. Instead, you have to replace the `FXAAPass` with:

```
var outputPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.CopyShader );
outputPass.renderToScreen = true;
composer.addPass( outputPass );
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/5091/

`three.js R91`

Comment: it woks, thanks! The resolution is better without fxaa, but worse than that without postprocessing. Is it an inevitable result of outline pass? Or how can I fix it?

Comment: `EffectComposer` does not regard the device pixel ratio so far (see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/12188). Besides, it's a WebGL1 limitation that you can't use MSAA with post processing. This will change with WebGL2.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the FXAA pass ([lines 295-298](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/28894ccbc0787257074dd21cfedacb844bfcca88/examples/webgl_postprocessing_outline.html#L297)), and enable `renderToScreen` for the outlinePass : `outlinePass.renderToScreen = true`

With postprocessing, the last pass with the property `renderToScreen` enabled will be rendered on the screen.

Also, be careful not to enable `renderToScreen` at different passes !